# opencv find index of members in Mat which are greater than zero

Tags: opencv

I have a `cv::Mat`, and I want to get the index of members which are greater than zero on the front several columns. In case I am not clear, I want to give an example:

```
double data[8] = {0.7, -0.1, 0.2, 0.4, 0.8, 0.7, -0.6, 0.3}
Mat example(2, 4, CV_64F, data);
```

The index of members greater than zero is:

```
index = {1 0 1 1 
         1 1 0 1}
```

And I want to get the first three columns of index:

```
final = {1 0 1 
         1 1 0}
```

Is there functions in OpenCV that I can use to solve this problem?

Thank you very much.

Comment: You could write your own function. That shouldn't be too hard, right?

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can do this in very simple way:

```
Mat index;
threshold(example, index, 0, 1, THRESH_BINARY);
Mat final = index(Rect(0,0,3,2));
// display result
cout << final << endl;
```

See [documentation of threshold function](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/miscellaneous_transformations.html#threshold).